# Disadvantage of oversampling

Tags: signal

What is the disadvantage of oversampling a signal?

For example, if I sample a signal at twice the Nyquist sampling rate, what will the disadvantages?

Comment: You asked the disadvantages, do you know the advantages? there are numerous advantages going beyond nyquist. If you like to really see the signal, you must sample 10x the expected frequency.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First thing: the Nyquist rate is not sufficient to obtain a correct sampling of a signal, it's just the theoretical minimum. Reasonable sampling rates go from twice the Nyquist rate (four-five times the maximum frequency) up.

Several ADC architectures use oversampling with averaging to obtain higher precision than the converter itself achieves. The extreme case is the one of sigma-delta converters, where a 1-bit ADC (just a comparator) is run at very high speed (\$2^N\$ samples/value, where N is the resolution in bits) to achieve the highest linearity, because the 1-bit conversion is linear by definition.

The drawback of oversampling is of course higher speed required for the ADC and the processing unit (higher complexity and cost), but there may be also other issues. You can see also that, at a given ADC speed, oversampling will require more time so an overall slower speed.

Another possible drawback is that it may result in additional noise if, for instance, the lower sampling speed allows you to integrate on a longer time.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need more processing power: you'll have to execute your filters twice as fast. This may come with higher power consumption and/or a higher price tag.

Answer (score 2):

Higher power consumption, possible loss in precision, more-so with capacitive successive approximation ADCs, and having to implement a faster data bus and number cruncher.

Answer (score 1):

Use of oversampling will tend to shift some of the filtering requirements from the analog domain to the digital domain.  If one's goal is to have an 8Khz output sample rate with a passband that extends to 3,500Hz, then if one doesn't use oversampling one will need to have an analog filter that drops like a rock between 3,500Hz and something between 4,000 and 4,500Hz.  If one uses 2x oversampling, and has digital software that can filter out everything above 3,999Hz, then the analog filter can have its transition range extend from 3,500Hz to almost 12,000Hz--a much easier job.  Using 4x oversampling, one could extend the analog filter's transition range up to 20,000Hz; designing a filter with a 2.5 octave transition region is a lot easier than designing one with a 1/3-octave transition range (generously assuming the stop band need not start until almost 4,500Hz).

The disadvantage of oversampling is that if one simplifies the analog filter design, that will require the digital filter to remove any unwanted signals which the analog filtering left in. Doubling the oversampling rate will require that the digital circuitry process twice as many samples per second, and may in some cases have to do more with each sample. Up to a certain point, being willing to accept a small increase in the cost of the digital filtering will allow one to achieve a bigger savings in the cost of the analog filtering, but beyond that point further increases in the oversampling ratio will impose increasing costs on the digital size, while achieving smaller and smaller savings on the analog side.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Higher Sampling Rate Increases the Data Rates to FPGAs

(2) there is setup and hold time issues come in picture

(3) higher power consumption

(4) if converter is used then one extra converter stage required so cost of devise increase

Comment: Right now this doesn't add much that isn't in the existing answers from 2 years ago.  If you have information that isn't already covered in other answers then you could expand your bullet points to explain the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Oversampling compresses the signal bandwidth to a smaller part of the frequency axis, and can make subtle filters harder to design and implement because of this.  You may, for example, need a filter that drops like a rock instead of something with a smaller slope, so you may need higher orders.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're saying here. The normal purpose of oversampling is to allow some filtering work to be done in the digital domain, so as to ease the requirements on the analog filtering.

Comment: @supercat I'm specifically referring to cases where you sample so fast that all your data bandwidth is all compressed on the frequency axis -  so compressed it's hard to deal with with digital filters.   You can always recover by decimating, but it has come up as a problem for me.

Comment: What sorts of sample rates and frequency content would you be expecting?

Comment: @supercat Odd stuff.  Sampling by necessity at 1k, freq of interest down below 0.5 Hz